# Hello everyone! I am trying to create GNN with RouteNet model

Tags: gnn, tensorflow-gnn

I have found this challenge called "Graph Neural Networking Challenge" https://bnn.upc.edu/challenge/gnnet2023/ and it's going on for 4 years. I have tried to use previous implementations for my curiosity. I was able to create datasets, but I can't train the model, because it's doesn't receive any input according to the error. For input data responsible file "read_dataset" and function "input_fn", which doesn't produce any output even though my datasets have data. Instead, it's just giving empty tensors such as: ({'traffic': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 'packets': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), and so on. Can someone help me to understand this tool and how I can make it work, please? I am really trying already for a long time.

I have access to my datasets and I see data there. I have tried to create datasets without function, but them model expects specific as input and wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you provide some example code and also use formatting possibilities with backticks?

Answer (score 1):

The full answer isn't clear to me from the question, but I suspect some clarification on tensor shapes may help:

A `None` entry in a `tf.TensorShape` means the actual size of that dimension is unknown. If so, the shape is said to be *not fully defined*. (A Tensor that's known to be empty will have at least one dimension of size 0, but that's different.)

In a `tf.data.Dataset`, not fully defined shapes can appear in the `Dataset.element_spec` attribute, meaning that the Tensors that will come out of the Dataset may vary in the size of that dimension.

It can also happen that a `tf.Tensor` object has a not-fully-defined shape, namely in places where it does not represent one actual, already known tensor value but merely serves as a placeholder in defining some future computation. That may seem a bit unusual but is explained well in TF's [Introduction to graphs and tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs). Notice that passing any Python function to `Dataset.map()` will turn it into a `tf.function`.

Finally, not-fully-defined shapes can be found on the symbolic tensors of the ["Functional API"](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional_api) of Keras, but from the question that does not seem to be the issue here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your answer helped a lot to make things clear. I got confused and thought there was an error in the function that I mentioned earlier, but my issue was due to the version of TF.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most welcome! Don't be shy to upvote it. ;-)